# Select max TASK_ID and CREATED_DATE - already tried MAX and DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to fetch only the second record and ignore the first one.
I have this data:

```
REFERENCE_NO       TASK_ID        CREATED_DATE
------------------------------------------------------------
244038             83102          2020-01-14 09:23:21:000000
244038             83114          2020-01-14 09:23:21:867000
```

Expected Output:

```
REFERENCE_NO       TASK_ID        CREATED_DATE
------------------------------------------------------------
244038             83114          2020-01-14 09:23:21:867000
```

Comment: What is your expected output and what you have tried please edit and include that query also in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query.

You can get the details and learn from the link [Aggregate Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
.

```
Select max(CREATED_DATE) as MaxCREATED_DATE
      , max(TASK_ID) as MaxTaskId
from yourtable
```

You can also try the below one.

```
Select REFERENCE_NO, max(CREATED_DATE) as MaxCREATED_DATE
      , max(TASK_ID) as MaxTaskId
from yourtable
group by REFERENCE_NO
```

Here is an implementation based on your sample data.

```
create table TestTable(REFERENCE_NO Varchar(10), TASK_ID int, CREATED_DATE Datetime)
insert into TestTable Values
('244038', 83102, '2020-01-14 09:23:21'),
('244038', 83114, '2020-01-14 09:23:21')

Select REFERENCE_NO, max(CREATED_DATE) as MaxCREATED_DATE
      , max(TASK_ID) as MaxTaskId
from TestTable
group by REFERENCE_NO
```

The output is:

```
REFERENCE_NO    MaxCREATED_DATE            MaxTaskId
----------------------------------------------------
244038          2020-01-14 09:23:21.000    83114
```

[Live db<>fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=636ff9db294285b3a318465de24541f9)

It looks like as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select REFERENCE_NO ,TASK_ID,CREATED_DATE from [dbo].[Table_1]
where TASK_ID in (select max(TASK_ID) from [dbo].[Table_1])
```

Comment: I have multiple REFERENCE_NO in this table and need to retrieve the max of each reference_no so this won't work for me.

Comment: what did you want max TASK_ID or max REFERENCE_NO ??? My query is only for max TASK_ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OFFSET`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by created_date
offset 1 row fetch first 1 row only;
```